# Упорядочить ряд чисел методом случайного выбора пары чисел

Tags: алгоритм

Это вопрос не мой, а какого-то человека с dxdy, поэтому проверку решения я сделать не смогу, но мне лично самому стала интересна данная задача.

Пользователь вводит перестановку длины N (в данном случае не более 10). Вы должны упорядочить ее по возрастанию.

Вам доступна только следующая операция: выбрать два различных случайных числа и, если правое меньше левого, поменять их местами.

Какое мат. ожидание количества операций, необходимых для упорядочивания введенного ряда?

В изначальном вопросе требовалось, чтобы в тестирующей системе (доступа к которой у нас, к сожалению, нет) программа отрабатывала на 40 рядах за три секунды, поэтому необходимо найти решение, имеющее вычислительную сложность меньшую, чем O(n!), или ее же, но с очень малой константой.

Пример:

```
Input:
4
1 3 2 4
_______
Output:
6.0
_______
Пояснение:
F(1324) = 5/6 * (F(1324) + 1) + 1/6 * (F(1234) + 1)
F(1234) = 0, так как уже является требуемой перестановкой
```

Comment: Вопрос не вполне понятен - если задано `доступна только следующая операция...`, о каком более оптимальном решении может идти речь?

Comment: @MBo Об оптимальном решении подсчета мат. ожидания для произвольного ряда

Comment: ОК, тогда что значит `чтобы программа отрабатывала на 40 рядах за три секунды` ?

Comment: @MBo обычная формулировка требований для олимпиадной задачи: приведите решение на любом поддерживаемом языке такое, чтобы оно за 3 секунды и 256 мб отрабатывало на любом подготовленном тесте. В нашем случае, нужно просто показать, что алгоритм решения лучше, чем O(n!) или имеет очень малую константу.

Comment: @EzikBro OK, ясно. До меня не доходило, что матожидание нужно посчитать для конкретного набора, а не абстрактной последовательности длиной n